# Writing a Power method with a minimum amount of steps n(log)N

Tags: java

I'm trying to write the Power method and now the question is how to write it in a better way. Here is my code, I've verified it works well for all the Power conditions, however I can't think on a better solution.

The real issue is how I express the power with a Negative exponent in `O(log)n` condition

```
public static double raiseToPowerIterative(double x, int n) {
    double sol = 1;
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (n > 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n;i++) {
            sol *= x;
        }
        return sol;
    } else if (n < 0){
        for (int i = -1; i >= n; i--) {
            sol /= x;
        }
    }
    return sol;
}
```

Comment: Your current solution appears to be O(n) for both positive and negative exponent. To make it O(log n) you could consider computing `x^2, x^4, x^8 ...` and working out how to quickly compute `x^n` from these values and the representation of `n` in binary

Comment: Also, the negative exponent isn't really a problem: if you've implemented this for `n >= 0`, and your caller passes `n < 0`, just do a single recursive call with `abs(n)` and `1 / x`

Answer (score 0):

You need some additional math rules, you are using:

- **x<sup>n</sup> = x.x. ... .x** (n times)

With O(n)

However

- **x<sup>2k</sup> = x<sup>k</sup> . x<sup>k</sup>**
- **x<sup>2k+1</sup> = x.x<sup>2k</sup>**

Which can deliver O(²log n), as you are doing exponents n → n/2 → n/2/2 → ... → 1.

Where you only need to calculate x<sup>k</sup> once.

*A recursive solution might be easiest; calling oneself for x<sup>k</sup>.*

---

***Your solution:***

That does not work, I think. As probably past limit date of the work.

***Wrong:***

```
double power(double x, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    boolean negative = ( n < 0 );
    if (negative) {
        n = -n;
    }
    double sol = 1;
    while (n > 0) {
        if (n%2 == 1) {
           sol *= x;
        }
        x *= x;
        n /= 2;
    }
    if (negative) {
        return 1 / sol;
    }
    return sol; 
}
```

Correct recursive:

```
double power(double x, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n < 0) {
        return 1 / power(x, -n);
    }
    double sqrPower = power(x, n/2);
    int p = sqrPower * sqrPower;
    if (n % 1 == 1) {
        p *= x;
    }
    return p;
}
```

That is, one has to do something with the *result* of the recursive call.
For an iterative loop one would need a stack to reconstruct the result.

Correct iterative:

```
double power(double x, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    boolean invert = n < 0;
    if (invert) {
        n = -n;
    }
    Stack<Double> factors = new Stack<>();
    while (n > 0) {
        factors.push(n % 1 == 1 ? x : 1.0);
        n /= 2;
    }
    double sol = 1;
    while (!factors.empty()) {
        double f = factors.pop();
        sol = sol * sol * f;
    }
    return invert ? 1/sol : sol;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works :)

if (n == 0){
    return 1;
    }
    boolean negative = ( n < 0 );
    if (negative){
    n = -n;
    }
    double sol = 1;
   
    
    
    while (n > 0){
        if (n%2 ==1)
        {
            sol *= x;
            
        }
        x *= x;
        n /= 2;
    }
        if (negative){
        return 1 / sol;
        }
        
    return sol;